# How do I decode and view a BLOB from a local database in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I have an SQLite DB that has a column with Blobs.

I have tried to access and display this BLOB but alas with no success.

Here is what I have tried:

```
Image.memory(Uint8List.view(myList[counterInt]['ItemImageBLOB'])),
```

I've tried also

```
Image.memory(Uint8List(myList[counterInt]['ItemImageBLOB'])),
```

The error I'm receiving is:

```
type '_Uint8ArrayView' is not a subtype of type 'ByteBuffer'
```

Answer (score 10, accepted):

if you also follow my case below 
Use the following directly

```
Image.memory(myList[counteInt]['ItemImageBLOB'])
```

In my example, I hard code and save this https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png to sqlite BLOB field

To show picutre

```
Image.memory(snapshot.data[index].pict)
```

when create sqlite table, your field type must be BLOB

```
await db.execute(
    "CREATE TABLE Employee(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, mobileno TEXT,emailId TEXT, pict BLOB )");
```

In your class , pict field must be type Uint8List

class Employee{

```
  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String mobileNo;
  String emailId;
  Uint8List pict;

  Employee(this.firstName, this.lastName,this.mobileNo,this.emailId, this.pict);

   Employee.fromMap(Map map) {
    firstName = map[firstName];
    lastName = map[lastName];
    mobileNo = map[mobileNo];
    emailId = map[emailId];
    pict = map[pict];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "mobileNo" : mobileNo,
    "emailId" : emailId,
    "pict": pict,
  };

}
```

demo execution

[image]

full working code

main.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:so_sqlite/database/dbhelper.dart';
import 'package:so_sqlite/model/employee.dart';
import 'package:so_sqlite/employeelist.dart';
import 'package:http/http.dart' show get;

void main() => runApp(new MyApp());

class MyApp extends StatelessWidget {
  // This widget is the root of your application.
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new MaterialApp(
      title: 'SQFLite DataBase Demo',
      theme: new ThemeData(
        primarySwatch: Colors.blue,
      ),
      home: new MyHomePage(title: 'Flutter Demo Home Page'),
    );
  }
}

class MyHomePage extends StatefulWidget {
  MyHomePage({Key key, this.title}) : super(key: key);
  final String title;

  @override
  _MyHomePageState createState() => new _MyHomePageState();
}

class _MyHomePageState extends State<MyHomePage> {
  Employee employee = new Employee("", "", "", "", null);

  String firstname;
  String lastname;
  String emailId;
  String mobileno;
  final scaffoldKey = new GlobalKey<ScaffoldState>();
  final formKey = new GlobalKey<FormState>();

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      key: scaffoldKey,
      appBar: new AppBar(title: new Text('Saving Employee'), actions: <Widget>[
        new IconButton(
          icon: const Icon(Icons.view_list),
          tooltip: 'Next choice',
          onPressed: () {
            navigateToEmployeeList();
          },
        ),
      ]),
      body: SingleChildScrollView(
        child: new Padding(
          padding: const EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
          child: new Form(
            key: formKey,
            child: new Column(
              children: [
                new TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'First Name'),
                  validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? "Enter FirstName" : null,
                  onSaved: (val) => this.firstname = val,
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.text,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Last Name'),
                  validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'Enter LastName' : null,
                  onSaved: (val) => this.lastname = val,
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.phone,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Mobile No'),
                  validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'Enter Mobile No' : null,
                  onSaved: (val) => this.mobileno = val,
                ),
                new TextFormField(
                  keyboardType: TextInputType.emailAddress,
                  decoration: new InputDecoration(labelText: 'Email Id'),
                  validator: (val) => val.length == 0 ? 'Enter Email Id' : null,
                  onSaved: (val) => this.emailId = val,
                ),
                new Container(
                  margin: const EdgeInsets.only(top: 10.0),
                  child: new RaisedButton(
                    onPressed: _submit,
                    child: new Text('Save'),
                  ),
                )
              ],
            ),
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }

  void _submit() async {
    if (this.formKey.currentState.validate()) {
      formKey.currentState.save();
    } else {
      return null;
    }

    var response = await get(
        "https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/7/70/Example.png");
    var bytesFromPict = response.bodyBytes;

    print("bytes : ${bytesFromPict}");

    var employee =
        Employee(firstname, lastname, mobileno, emailId, bytesFromPict);
    var dbHelper = DBHelper();
    dbHelper.saveEmployee(employee);
    _showSnackBar("Data saved successfully");
  }

  void _showSnackBar(String text) {
    scaffoldKey.currentState
        .showSnackBar(new SnackBar(content: new Text(text)));
  }

  void navigateToEmployeeList() {
    Navigator.push(
      context,
      new MaterialPageRoute(builder: (context) => new MyEmployeeList()),
    );
  }
}
```

employeelist.dart

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:so_sqlite/model/employee.dart';
import 'dart:async';
import 'package:so_sqlite/database/dbhelper.dart';

Future<List<Employee>> fetchEmployeesFromDatabase() async {
  var dbHelper = DBHelper();
  Future<List<Employee>> employees = dbHelper.getEmployees();
  return employees;
}

class MyEmployeeList extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  MyEmployeeListPageState createState() => new MyEmployeeListPageState();
}

class MyEmployeeListPageState extends State<MyEmployeeList> {
  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return new Scaffold(
      appBar: new AppBar(
        title: new Text('Employee List'),
      ),
      body: new Container(
        padding: new EdgeInsets.all(16.0),
        child: new FutureBuilder<List<Employee>>(
          future: fetchEmployeesFromDatabase(),
          builder: (context, snapshot) {
            if (snapshot.hasData) {
              return new ListView.builder(
                  itemCount: snapshot.data.length,
                  itemBuilder: (context, index) {
                    return new Column(
                        crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
                        children: <Widget>[
                          new Text(snapshot.data[index].firstName,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 18.0)),
                          new Text(snapshot.data[index].lastName,
                              style: new TextStyle(
                                  fontWeight: FontWeight.bold, fontSize: 14.0)),
                          Image.memory(snapshot.data[index].pict),
                          new Divider()
                        ]);
                  });
            } else if (snapshot.hasError) {
              return new Text("${snapshot.error}");
            }
            return new Container(alignment: AlignmentDirectional.center,child: new CircularProgressIndicator(),);
          },
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

model\employee.dart

```
import 'dart:math';
import 'dart:typed_data';

class Employee{

  String firstName;
  String lastName;
  String mobileNo;
  String emailId;
  Uint8List pict;

  Employee(this.firstName, this.lastName,this.mobileNo,this.emailId, this.pict);

   Employee.fromMap(Map map) {
    firstName = map[firstName];
    lastName = map[lastName];
    mobileNo = map[mobileNo];
    emailId = map[emailId];
    pict = map[pict];
  }

  Map<String, dynamic> toMap() => {
    "firstName": firstName,
    "lastName": lastName,
    "mobileNo" : mobileNo,
    "emailId" : emailId,
    "pict": pict,
  };

}
```

database\dbhelper.dart

```
import 'dart:async';
import 'dart:io' as io;
import 'package:path/path.dart';
import 'package:sqflite/sqflite.dart';
import 'package:path_provider/path_provider.dart';
import 'package:so_sqlite/model/employee.dart';

class DBHelper {
  static Database _db;

  Future<Database> get db async {
    if (_db != null) return _db;
    _db = await initDb();
    return _db;
  }

  initDb() async {
    io.Directory documentsDirectory = await getApplicationDocumentsDirectory();
    String path = join(documentsDirectory.path, "test1.db");
    var theDb = await openDatabase(path, version: 1, onCreate: _onCreate);
    return theDb;
  }

  void _onCreate(Database db, int version) async {
    // When creating the db, create the table
    await db.execute(
        "CREATE TABLE Employee(id INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, firstname TEXT, lastname TEXT, mobileno TEXT,emailId TEXT, pict BLOB )");
    print("Created tables");
  }

  void saveEmployee(Employee employee) async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    await dbClient.insert("Employee", employee.toMap());
    /*await dbClient.transaction((txn) async {
      return await txn.rawInsert(
          'INSERT INTO Employee(firstname, lastname, mobileno, emailid, pict ) VALUES(' +
              '\'' +
              employee.firstName +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              employee.lastName +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              employee.mobileNo +
              '\'' +
              ',' +
              '\'' +
              employee.emailId +
              '\'' +
              employee.pict +
              '\'' +
              ')');
    });*/
  }

  Future<List<Employee>> getEmployees() async {
    var dbClient = await db;
    List<Map> list = await dbClient.rawQuery('SELECT * FROM Employee');
    List<Employee> employees = new List();
    for (int i = 0; i < list.length; i++) {
      employees.add(new Employee(list[i]["firstname"], list[i]["lastname"], list[i]["mobileno"], list[i]["emailid"], list[i]["pict"]));
    }
    print(employees.length);
    return employees;
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you so much!!